# Implement Google as a identity provider(IDP) using Kentor Auth Service Library in MVC Application?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, owin, saml-2.0, kentor-authservices

Hi i am using kentor auth services(The Kentor Authentication services is a library that adds SAML2P support to ASP.NET and IIS web sites, allowing the web site to act as a SAML2 Service Provider (SP) ).Right now i am using Google as a Identity Privider for testing my application **(Authentication using owin midddleware**).I have set Up Google Identity provider also.But When i run the application it gives me an error

**"400. That’s an error.
Invalid Request, invalid idpId in request URL, check if SSO URL is configured properly on SP side. That’s all we know."**

i have used SingleSignOnServiceUrl=https://accounts.google.com/o/saml2/idp?idpid=xxxxxxxxx

DiscoveryServiceUrl=https://accounts.google.com/o/saml2/idp?idpid=xxxxxxxxx

Is that above configuration is correct?

I have attached App_start configuration below.This from Kentor auth services library.

```
public partial class Startup
{
    // For more information on configuring authentication, please visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301864
    public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        // Configure the db context, user manager and signin manager to use a single instance per request
        app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationDbContext.Create);
        app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);
        app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationSignInManager>(ApplicationSignInManager.Create);

        // Enable the application to use a cookie to store information for the signed in user
        // and to use a cookie to temporarily store information about a user logging in with a third party login provider
        // Configure the sign in cookie
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
            LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
            Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
            {
                // Enables the application to validate the security stamp when the user logs in.
                // This is a security feature which is used when you change a password or add an external login to your account.  
                OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser>(
                    validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
                    regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager))
            }
        });
        app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);

        app.UseKentorAuthServicesAuthentication(CreateAuthServicesOptions());
    }

    private static KentorAuthServicesAuthenticationOptions CreateAuthServicesOptions()
    {
        var spOptions = CreateSPOptions();
        var authServicesOptions = new KentorAuthServicesAuthenticationOptions(false)
        {
            SPOptions = spOptions
        };

        var idp = new IdentityProvider(new EntityId("~/App_Data/GoogleIDPMetadata.xml"), spOptions)
            {
                AllowUnsolicitedAuthnResponse = true,
                Binding = Saml2BindingType.HttpRedirect,
                SingleSignOnServiceUrl = new Uri("https://accounts.google.com/o/saml2/idp?idpid=xxxxxxxxx")
            };

        idp.SigningKeys.AddConfiguredKey(
            new X509Certificate2(
                HostingEnvironment.MapPath(
                    "~/App_Data/Kentor.AuthServices.StubIdp.cer")));

        authServicesOptions.IdentityProviders.Add(idp);

        // It's enough to just create the federation and associate it
        // with the options. The federation will load the metadata and
        // update the options with any identity providers found.
        new Federation("http://example.com/Federation", true, authServicesOptions);

        return authServicesOptions;
    }

    private static SPOptions CreateSPOptions()
    {
        var swedish = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("sv-se");

        var organization = new Organization();
        organization.Names.Add(new LocalizedName("Kentor", swedish));
        organization.DisplayNames.Add(new LocalizedName("Kentor IT AB", swedish));
        organization.Urls.Add(new LocalizedUri(new Uri("http://www.kentor.se"), swedish));

        var spOptions = new SPOptions
        {
            EntityId = new EntityId("https://example.com/AuthServices"),
            ReturnUrl = new Uri("https://example.com/Account/ExternalLoginCallback"),
            DiscoveryServiceUrl = new Uri(https://accounts.google.com/o/saml2/idp?idpid=xxxxxxxxx"),
            Organization = organization
        };

        var techContact = new ContactPerson
        {
            Type = ContactType.Technical
        };
        techContact.EmailAddresses.Add("authservices@example.com");
        spOptions.Contacts.Add(techContact);

        var supportContact = new ContactPerson
        {
            Type = ContactType.Support
        };
        supportContact.EmailAddresses.Add("support@example.com");
        spOptions.Contacts.Add(supportContact);

        var attributeConsumingService = new AttributeConsumingService("AuthServices")
        {
            IsDefault = true,
        };

        attributeConsumingService.RequestedAttributes.Add(
            new RequestedAttribute("urn:someName")
            {
                FriendlyName = "Some Name",
                IsRequired = true,
                NameFormat = RequestedAttribute.AttributeNameFormatUri
            });

        attributeConsumingService.RequestedAttributes.Add(
            new RequestedAttribute("Minimal"));

        spOptions.AttributeConsumingServices.Add(attributeConsumingService);

        spOptions.ServiceCertificates.Add(new X509Certificate2(
            AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ApplicationBase + "/App_Data/Kentor.AuthServices.Tests.pfx"));

        return spOptions;
    }
```

Why i am getting 400 error when i redirect to google saml page? Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi #Selvan, were you able to setup google idp ?

Comment: Yes,I made it work.It is working now.

Comment: can you post me link to your sample code ?

Comment: Hi #Selvan, can you post me link to sample code ?

Comment: @VetriSelvan If you have solved this can you please add it as an answer so that it would help others ?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK Google offers no discovery service. Remove the `DiscoveryServiceUrl` from the configuration.

Also you should really clean up the configuration and not use the sample application's config.

For testing you can also use the Stub idp that is included in the project at which is available at http://stubidp.kentor.se

Comment: Hi @Anders Abel.i have already tested with this http://stubidp.kentor.se test IDP.It works fabulous. I can login using this test IDP with my mvc application.But when i am using with Google IDP i always getting error " invalid idpId in request URL, check if SSO URL is configured properly on SP side"

Comment: This is not a chat system. If I've answered the question, please mark it as accepted. Comments are only to be used if something with my response is unclear. If you want to chat, join https://gitter.im/KentorIT/authservices.